# Sampling at exactly Nyquist rate in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling

Today I have stumbled upon a strange outcome in matlab. Lets say I have a sine wave such that

```
f = 1;
Fs = 2*f;
t = linspace(0,1,Fs);    
x = sin(2*pi*f*t);
plot(x)
```

and the outcome is in the figure.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eUse3MO.jpg]

when I set,

```
f = 100
```

outcome is in the figure below,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv0t9.jpg]

What is the exact reason of this? It is the Nyquist sampling theorem, thus it should have generated the sine properly. Of course when I take **Fs >> f** I get better results and a very good sine shape. My explenation to myself is that Matlab was having hardtime with floating numbers but I am not so sure if this is true at all. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say your English is pretty good :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case you only generate 2 samples (the third input of `linspace` is number of samples), so it's hard to see anything.

In the second case you generate 200 samples from time 0 to 1 (including those two values). So the sampling period is 1/199, and the sampling frequency is 199, which is slightly below the Nyquist rate. So *there is aliasing*: you see the original signal of frequency 100 plus its alias at frequency 99.

In other words: the following code reproduces your second figure:

```
t = linspace(0,1,200);
x = .5*sin(2*pi*99*t) -.5*sin(2*pi*100*t);
plot(x)
```

The `.5` and `-.5` above stem from the fact that a sine wave can be decomposed as the sum of two spectral deltas at positive and negative frequencies, and the coefficients of those deltas have opposite signs.

The sum of those two sinusoids is equivalent to *amplitude modulation*, namely a sine of frequency 99.5 modulated by a sine of frequency 1/2. Since time spans from 0 to 1, the modulator signal (whose frequency is 1/2) only completes half a period. That's what you see in your second figure.

---

To avoid aliasing you need to increase sample rate above the Nyquist rate. Then, to recover the original signal from its samples you can use an ideal low pass filter with cutoff frequency Fs/2. In your case, however, since you are sampling *below* the Nyquist rate, you would *not* recover the signal at frequency 100, but rather its alias at frequency 99.

Had you sampled *above* the Nyquist rate, for example Fs = 201, the orignal signal *could* ideally be recovered from the samples.<sup>†</sup> But that would require an almost ideal low pass filter, with a *very sharp* transition between passband and stopband. Namely, the alias would now be at frequency 101 and should be rejected, whereas the desired signal would be at frequency 100 and should be passed.

To *relax the filter requirements* you need can *sample well above the Nyquist rate*. That way the aliases are further appart from the signal and the filter has an easier job separating signal from aliases.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> That doesn't mean the graph *looks* like your original signal (see [SergV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29692268/2586922)); it only means that after ideal lowpass filtering it will.</sup>

Comment: first of all, i didnt understand what you mean by "sum of sines". there isnt a sum of sines in this code. am I understanding it wrong? second is, there shouldnt be aliasing? it is the Nyquist rate. lets write "t = [0:Fs-1]/Fs;" instead of linspace line. in this case f=1 does not change but f=100 becomes even more nonsense. the figure in the link is for f=100, http://i.imgur.com/vzZx5qX.jpg

Comment: Read my answer more carefully. The sum of sines refers to the fact that _there is aliasing: you see the original signal of frequency 100 plus its alias at frequency 99_. That's the sum I mean. And as I said, your sampling frequency is not what you think it is, because `linspace` includes both 0 and 1 in the 200-sample output (that's also written in my answer)

Comment: Yes after i have read the edited answer with code I understood what you mean. Then say for f=100 what should be the code so that Fs = 2*f, exactly the Nyquist sampling rate and creates appropriate plots?

Comment: To get sampling rate `Fs` use `t = linspace(0,1-1/Fs,Fs);`

Comment: But note that in that case the two sinousoids exactly cancel each other. You need a higher sample rate

Comment: It was an interesting question :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not related to the Nyquist theorem and aliasing. It is simple problem of graphic representation. You can change your code that frequency of sine will be lower Nyquist limit, but graph will be as strange as before:

```
t = linspace(0,1,Fs+2);
plot(sin(2*pi*f*t));
```

Result: 
[image]

To explain problem I modify your code:

```
Fs=100;
f=12;  %f << Fs
t=0:1/Fs:0.5; % step =1/Fs
t1=0:1/(10*Fs):0.5;   % step=1/(10*Fs) for precise graphic representation
subplot (2, 1, 1);
plot(t,sin(2*pi*f*t),"-b",t,sin(2*pi*f*t),"*r");
subplot (2, 1, 2);
plot(t1,sin(2*pi*f*t1),"g",t,sin(2*pi*f*t),"r*");
```

See result:
[image]

- Red star - values of **sin(2*pi*f)** with sampling rate of **Fs**.
- Blue line - lines which connect red stars. It is usual data representation  of function **plot()** - line interpolation between data points
- Green curve - **sin(2*pi*f)**

Your eyes and brain can easily understand that these graphs represent the sine

Change frequency to more high:

```
f=48;   % 2*f < Fs !!!
```

[image]

See on blue lines and red stars. Your eyes and brain do not understand now that these graphs represent the same sine. But your "red stars" are actually valid value of sine. See on bottom graph.

Finally, there is the same graphics for sine with frequency **f=50** (2*f = Fs):

[image]

P.S.

Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem states for your case that if:

1. **f < 2*Fs**
2. You have *infinite* number of samples (red stars on our plots)

then you can reproduce  values of function in any time (green curve on our plots). You must use **sinc interpolation** to do it.

Comment: I agree that the graph will have that appearance even sampling above Nyquist rate. But if you sample above Nyquist rate you can recover the original signal through ideal filtering (as my answer explains), whereas if you sample below Nyquist rate you can't

Comment: @LuisMendo, Yes, you are right about  recover the original signal, but tuncarslan was confusion by shape of sine on graph. (citate - "What is the exact reason of this? It is the Nyquist sampling theorem, thus it should have generated the sine properly.")  His problem (except not quite correct matlab code) was not  irrelevant to Nyquist theorem. I hope that he will understand the  Nyquist theorem better after this discussion.

Comment: You are right. I focused on recovering the signal, not on how the actual samples look like. I've added a link to your answer in mine

Answer (score 0):

copied from Matlab Help:

linspace

Generate linearly spaced vectors
Syntax

```
y = linspace(a,b)
y = linspace(a,b,n)
```

Description

The linspace function generates linearly spaced vectors. It is similar to the colon operator ":", but gives direct control over the number of points.

y = linspace(a,b) generates a row vector y of 100 points linearly spaced between and including a and b.

y = linspace(a,b,n) generates a row vector y of n points linearly spaced between and including a and b. For n < 2, linspace returns b.
Examples

Create a vector of 100 linearly spaced numbers from 1 to 500:

```
A = linspace(1,500);
```

Create a vector of 12 linearly spaced numbers from 1 to 36:

```
A = linspace(1,36,12);
```

Answer (score 0):

linspace is not apparent for Nyquist interval, so you can use the common form:

```
t = 0:Ts:1;
```

or

```
t = 0:1/Fs:1;
```

and change the Fs values.

The first Figure is due to the approximation of '0': sin(0) and sin(2*pi). We can notice the range is in 10^(-16) level.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the function [reconstruct_FFT](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57651-reconstruct-fft-upsampling-and-interpolation) that can recover critically sampled data even for short observation intervals if the input sequence of samples is periodic. It performs lowpass filtering in the frequency domain.